# MySQL UNION - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, union

I am looking for a solution:

```
SELECT SUM(`quant`), MONTH(`date`) AS month, `id` from (
(SELECT `date`, `id`, count(`hit`) AS `quant ` FROM `stat_2014_07` WHERE `k_id` = '123') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT `date`, `id`, count(`hit`) AS `quant ` FROM `stat_2014_08` WHERE `k_id ` = '123') 
) group by id, month
```

MySQL: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: You'd add an alias, by gving subqueries a name after your closing `)`. So, something like `(SELECT foo FROM bar) thisisaderivedtablealias`. You can omit the `()`'s around the 2 inner queries in your UNION ALL BTW.

Comment: Tables that have the same structure but only different in their names are usually sign of bad database design.  A `union all` would be unnecessary if you had a single table called `stats` that had data from all the months.

Answer (score 17):

Exactly what the error message says. In your (simplified) query:

```
SELECT SUM(`quant`), MONTH(`date`) AS month, `id` 
from (
  ... inner select 
) 
group by id, month;
```

You didn't specify an alias for the derived table. So it should be:

```
SELECT SUM(`quant`), MONTH(`date`) AS month, `id` 
from (
  ... inner select 
) as t -- this is the change
group by id, month;
```

Btw: the parentheses around the select parts of a union are totally useless. I suggest removing them for clarity:

```
SELECT SUM(`quant`), MONTH(`date`) AS month, `id` 
from (
  SELECT `date`, `id`, count(`hit`) AS `quant ` FROM `stat_2014_07` WHERE `k_id` = '123'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT `date`, `id`, count(`hit`) AS `quant ` FROM `stat_2014_08` WHERE `k_id ` = '123'
) as t -- this is the change
group by id, month;
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to give aliases to your queries:

```
SELECT   SUM(`quant`), MONTH(`date`) AS month, `id` 
FROM     ((SELECT `date`, `id`, count(`hit`) AS `quant` 
           FROM   `stat_2014_07` 
           WHERE  `k_id` = '123') t1
          UNION ALL 
          (SELECT `date`, `id`, count(`hit`) AS `quant` 
           FROM   `stat_2014_08` 
           WHERE  `k_id ` = '123') t2
         ) t_union
GROUP BY id, month
```

Comment: I think adding `t_union` is enough and we should not add `t1` and `t2` for the inner queries, because that gives us the same error. 
FYI I'm using MySQL 5.7.42.